# SpeakerRecognition - Identifying more than one speaker in an audio - C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-cognitive-services

Working with the SpeakerRecognitionAPI, I have successfully been able enroll and identify a speaker. Now, I have multiple users speaking in an audio, How to identify multiple user from the audio? I have been searching alot since 5 hours but couldnt find anything. Any help would be appreciated.Thanks. I am working on .net MVC structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after dense research. You will have to send the identification profiles ids separated by comma in order to find out the profiles speaking in the audio but there is no support of diarization as if now. Moving to google speech api because well it gives that feature.

Answer (score 1):

You just have to enroll of your users like you did with the 1st one, and then query `Identification` method of `Speaker Recognition` part of the API, passing in input the Ids of the identification profiles

See API Method here:
https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/563309b6778daf02acc0a508/operations/5645c523778daf217c292592

Be careful, you can only limit to 10 Ids...

[image: API doc]

Comment: Is it possible to track down two different speakers in the same wav audio?

Comment: Also, can it be achieved via the nuget package Microsoft.ProjectOxford.SpeakerRecognition